# Win8 metro style apps won't update - old code still running?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to learn Windows 8 metro style app development but every time I run in VS11 it seems that the code is not updating. For example, this is what my debug windows looks like:

[image: Nonsense debugging]

The only way I can get a code change to run is to restart the machine! I've tried killing my 'app' in task manager to no avail.

Comment: Have you redeployed between debugging sessions?

Comment: So F5 doesn't do that? I'm running on the Local Machine. I did try actually clicking 'deploy' though and that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I have discovered that if you end the debugging session certain ways, the program does not stop running correctly. That can cause the behavior you are seeing. The best way I have found to avoid it is to alt-tab back to Visual Studio and use the Stop Debugging button to kill the Metro app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Win8 developer preview VS has some heuristics when it comes to deploying applications in order to reduce time to deploy. If for some reason you don't see your app getting updated on F5 a last recourse is to uninstall your app from the start screen and then on the F5 you should have a brand new deployment, you might also want to try a clean build depending on your app.